# Android studio has wrong name in menu bar

Tags: android-studio

The menu bar on the Android Studio window on Windows 10 has the app name "PlayPen". I have changed this name to "BabyClix" absolutely everywhere in the app after reading multiple SO articles and searching Android Studio, yet "PlayPen" just keeps being there.

Where does this name keep coming from, and how do I change this please?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Found it, the answer is in `settings.gradle` under `Gradle Scripts`.